# why doesn't EM waves get weaker as we travel further away from the source

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I know that as we get further away from the charge or from the magnetic field source both **magnetic field** and **electric field** **decreases** ,so *why don't electromagnetic waves get weaker as the travel further from the source?*

Comment: They do get weaker. Imagine holding a torch with your hand right in front of it and then a bit farther away. The first case will be brighter.

Comment: Of course they do.  Why would you think otherwise?  Are you assuming that plane wave solutions come from a point source?